# Overflying the 100 hour when airplane is not for hire

Tags: faa-regulations, aircraft-maintenance

Suppose I have a 100 hour inspection at 2000 hours total time. From 2100 to 2190 the aircraft is not being operated for hire. If I then have a 100 hour inspection at 2190, when is the next due?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its good until 2290 on the clock. If you look at the wording [of the FAR](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.409)

> (b) Except as provided in paragraph (c) of this section, no person may
> operate an aircraft carrying any person (other than a crewmember) for
> hire, and no person may give flight instruction for hire in an
> aircraft which that person provides, **unless within the preceding 100
> hours of time in service the aircraft has received an annual or
> 100-hour inspection and been approved for return to service in
> accordance with part 43 of this chapter** or has received an inspection
> for the issuance of an airworthiness certificate in accordance with
> part 21 of this chapter. The 100-hour limitation may be exceeded by
> not more than 10 hours while en route to reach a place where the
> inspection can be done. The excess time used to reach a place where
> the inspection can be done must be included in computing the next 100
> hours of time in service.

In other words when you are operating the aircraft in a situation where the 100 hour inspection is required, to be legal for such operations, such inspection had to have occurred at some point in the last 100 hours (or within the last 110 hours if you are flying the aircraft to a location to have the inspection done).